# Eclipse: 'Ignore optional compile problems' per worksapce possible?

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, compiler-errors, warnings

Eclipse offers a functionality to ignore optional compile problems on a per-project base for defined source folders. (You can access it via `Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source`.)

Is there any way to define this ignore-rule on a per-workspace scope? I have many modules which contain generated code. The source-folders of the generated code have always the same name.

Answer (score -1):

I am not aware of an option exactly like that anywhere else, but you can configure workspace wide how the builder handles things.  Go to Windows->Preferences then:

Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings

You'll see most of the classes of compilation issues organized somewhat logically.  You can also set specific project settings in the same place.

Comment: You're right. You can configure workspace-wide how the builder 'handles things'. But unfortunately not the 'thing' I asked for. Ignoring source folders is not possible from there. Or do I miss anything?